# CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssl, nagios, nrpe

I've just moved to a new nagios server and have got all the old hosts/services working. There is just one host that will not allow nrpe checks, producing an error on the nagios server as in the title.

The host produces the following error in syslog -

```
  user nrpe[4655]: Host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is not allowed to talk to us!
```

I've edited /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg and added XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and 127.0.0.1 to allowed_hosts.

I've also added ALL: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to /etc/hosts.allow

The old nagios server's IP isnt in either of those config files yet it can still perform the checks whereas the new nagios server cant and the host cant even perform the check on itself -

```
/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_load
```

Gives the same error as in the title and the

```
user nrpe[4655]: Host 127.0.0.1 is not allowed to talk to us!
```

in the syslog. Any help would be great, I've got to the point where I have no idea what else to try! The host is running Ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that is worth checking, is if the process is still running:

```
ps aux | grep nrpe
```

Find the PID of nrpe and then kill the PID:

```
nagios     538  0.0  0.1  22712  1048 ?        Ss   Feb13  13:33 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg -d
root     21910  0.0  0.0   7636   912 pts/0    S+   06:11   0:00 grep --color=auto nrpe
```

Then:

```
kill 538
```

Then start NRPE again and see if it works:

```
 /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg -d
```